Reconstruction without autofluorescence
I would like an image on which you can see the spatial (2D) distribution of a coating on a material.
For this purpose, the material with which the coating is made was fluorescently labeled (fluoresces only in the red channel r)
I have two fluorescence images.
Image 1 (control): uncoated material
Image 2 (sample): coated material
Challenge: The control shows autofluorescence in all color channels (red r, green g and blue b).
Assumption1: The intensity of the sample = intensity of the autofluorescence of the material + intensity of the coating
Assumption2: the ratio of the intensities of r:b or r:g of the autofluorescence of the uncoated material is constant in each case.
Problem: the section, size, nature and orientation of the material of the control and sample are not identical.
Is there a way to determine the fluorescence intensity of the coating alone?
Idea: Somehow compare the normalized intensity distributions (histograms) of the colour channels of the control and thus determine the ratio(s) (assumption 2). Then calculate the intensity distribution of the pure material in channel r from one of the intensity distributions of channels g or b of the sample and thus calculate the intensity distribution of the pure coating of the sample. This information is then used to reconstruct the image of the pure coating. Presumably you can make the method even more robust by using both ratios, perhaps a weighted average, where the weighting of the channel that has a greater intensity:exposure time ratio is greater.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks & regards
Kai
P.S.: I know that e.g. FLIM etc. would be a better alternative

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
